# Island Solution with ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I'd like to share with you a island solution I had to implement in ANTLR4.

1. Structure of the language. The language I had to write the grammar for is derived from
   PL/SQL with some additional constructs. I won't go into more details here as this is off topic.
2. The language defines a special command `PUT` with the following structure:

   `PUT [<SPECIALISED LANGUAGE>]`.

**My solution was:**

1. Override Lexer's `nextToken` method:

   ```
   public Token nextToken() {
       if (f_current_idx != -1) {
           _input.seek(f_current_idx); f_current_idx = -1;
       }
       Token l_token = super.nextToken(); return l_token;
   }
   ```
2. Add some code in the Lexer:

   ```
   PUT :
   'PUT'
   {
       f_current_idx = _input.index(); ((ANTLRStringStream) _input).rewind();

       SRC_PUTLexer l_put_lexer = new SRC_PUTLexer(_input);
       UnbufferedTokenStream<Token> l_tokenStream = new UnbufferedTokenStream<Token>(l_put_lexer);

       if (l_tokenStream.LA(2) == SRC_PUTLexer.LBRACK) { 
           new SRC_PUTParser(l_tokenStream).start_rule(); f_current_idx = _input.index();
       } 
   };
   ```

Furthermore the class `ANTLRStringStream` which has disappeared in ANTLR 4 had to be defined:

```
public class ANTLRStringStream extends ANTLRInputStream {

    protected int markDepth = 0;
    protected int lastMarker;

    protected ArrayList<Integer> markers;

    public ANTLRStringStream() {
        super();
    }

    public ANTLRStringStream(String input) {
        super(input);
    }

    public int mark() {
        if ( markers==null ) { markers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); }
        markers.add(markDepth, index()); markDepth++; lastMarker = markDepth;
        return markDepth;
    }

    public void rewind(int m) {
        int state = (int) markers.get(m); seek(state); release(m);
    }

    public void rewind() { rewind(lastMarker); }

    public void release(int marker) {
        markDepth = marker; markDepth--;
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be very welcome!
Kind regards, Wolfgang Hämmer

Answer (score 3):

This should really be a community wiki.

My first **major** comment is you need to get rid of the `ANTLRStringStream` class. The [`ANTLRInputStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRInputStream.java) class provided by ANTLR 4 provides the functionality of `ANTLRStringStream` in ANTLR 3. The [`IntStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.java) and [`CharStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream.java) interfaces were revised and extensively documented in ANTLR 4 to get rid of the problematic `rewind` methods and other undefined behavior. You should not reintroduce them.